# Rewrite a simple url for an image

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How to redirect this url :

`http://www.mydomain.com/logo/logo-mail-2008.gif`

to this one containing the `gif`

`http://www.mydomain.com/images/logo/logo-mail-2008.gif`

The host must match only `www.mydomain.com` as we've multiple hosts. I've managed something out but route rewriting isn't my best skill What do you think of :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /logo/logo-mail-2008.gif  
RewriteRule ^/images/logo/logo-mail-2008.gif$ [R=301,L]
```

PS: It would be best if this rewrite cond will live straight in the `vhost` in order to prevent the `.htaccess` from being parsed on each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost right.
Here is the correct syntax for what you want

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^logo/logo-mail-2008\.gif$ /images/logo/logo-mail-2008.gif [R=301,L]
```